# What problems can be caused by using PUBLIC or INTERFACE for target_include_directories in cmake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I'm seeing a lot of C and C++ libraries that don't provide `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` settings for `target_include_directories`.

I use put these settings into all my libraries, and I find it pretty useful that way: use `target_link_libraries` to add the library, and you get all the `-I`, `-L` and `-l` (or equivalent) settings you need, automatically. I haven't noticed any problems from doing this using the Ninja and Visual Studio generators, but I haven't used any others.

I've considered submitting pull requests and patches to "fix" this "problem" when I've seen it, but I'm wondering if there's some reason this would be a bad idea. Is there a technical reason not to use public or interface settings for this? What issues can it cause?

Comment: Why do you think they are there to create problems?

Comment: I don't - and I've indeed experienced no problems myself. But if I'm going to suggest to people that this would be a change worth making, I'd like to know what problems there might be.